# what is the difference between ごとに and おきに?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning

Both  ごとに and おきに appear to mean "repeatedly at intervals".

What is the difference between these two expressions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

１日おきに = ２日ごとに (every other day, every second day)
●○●○●○●...

２日おきに = ３日ごとに (every three days, every third day)

●○○●○○●○○●...

ごとに(毎に) [ごとに @weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%94%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB)
おきに(置きに) [2日置きに @weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/2%E6%97%A5%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB)

おき(置き) came from the verb 置く(leave). I think it's like "an interval (between the actions)" here. cf. 「[間隔]{かんかく}を[置]{お}く」

Comment: Nice usage of the black & white dots.  Thanks for confirming my suspicions on the difference.  But is there a way to say "Skip every third day" with `おきに`?  Like ●●○●●○...?

Comment: @istrasci う～～ん・・「３日に２日」かなあ・・・？？わからへん！ww

Comment: @istrasci: 三日に二日, which Chocolate mentioned, roughly means what you want, but I think that 三日に二日 refers more to the ratio 2/3 than the regular pattern of Yes-Yes-No-Yes-Yes-No-….  I do not think that there is a concise phrase which exactly describes this patter Yes-Yes-No-Yes-Yes-No-…, either in English or in Japanese, unless you count expressions such as 二日おきに休む as what you want.